# Person-years and relevance to incidence of condition

Tags: epidemiology

If the annual incidence (age and sex-adjusted) of a particular condition x is 21.8 cases per 100,000 person-years and this data was determined in one geographic location, then is it correct to say in a city of 1 million people that we may see that same condition, in one year, in approximately 21.8 x 10 = 218 people? I'm just trying to provide some relevance to a group of students on how common some conditions may be. I understand that the exact incidence would vary along with demographic, geographic and environmental features.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about statistics rather than biology.

Comment: David is there any way to easily get this question into statsexchange?

Comment: I'm not a moderator so I can't transfer it for you. You could just  copy and paste it there and then delete it from here as it's your question and nobody has answered yet. (They don't like the same question posted on two SE lists.)